# Improving execution time of this nested loop

Tags: python, performance, optimization, sympy

**Background.**

I've written a `Python` script which attempts to solve the Time Delay of Arrival (TDoA) multilateration problem in `3D` using `3` receivers. While a solution is relatively trivial in the `2D`/`3` or `3D`/`4` case, determining a solution in the `3D`/`3` case is difficult as the underlying system of equations is underdetermined. The specifics are outside the scope of this post. You may wish to read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration).

In my solution, I begin by modeling the setup as the system of equations:

I pass this system to `SymPy`'s symbolic solver `solve()`, which is able to quickly and effectively constrain the solution to a plane, given as `x` in terms of `y` and `z`.

Lastly, as with brute force, I simply iterate over all points `y/z` in the plane (within some bounds), compute `x` according to the plane equation found previously, then find the `rss` error for the that solution point. That point with least `rss` error gives the solution.

In my case, this works surprisingly well most of the time. I wish to feed a large experimental dataset to this algorithm and, as long as the solutions are "good" on average, this approach should be sufficient.

*Notice that an exact, or even approximate, solution cannot be determined from a system of equations.*

---

**Problem.**

Unfortunately, however, the loop used to iterate over all possible points in the plane is quite slow and, for my purposes and considering the size of my dataset, impractically so. My full code can be found below. I reproduce the loop in question here (if only for illustrative purposes):

```
        fx = 0; fy = 0; fz = 0; px = 0; err1 = 100; err2 = 0;
 
        for i in range(lower_bound, upper_bound):
            for j in range(lower_bound, upper_bound):
                # Find x for y = i, z = j
                px = soln[x].subs([(y, i), (z, j)])
                err2 = self.err(px, i, j, data)

                if(err2 < err1):
                    err1 = err1
                    fx = px; fy = i; fz = j
```

While I'm not terribly well-versed in `Python`, I suspect there is no "direct" way to improve the execution time of this loop. However, perhaps there's another way (perhaps some `SymPy` method I'm unaware of) that could be used.

---

**How can I improve the execution time of this loop?**

---

**Full code.**

```
import sympy as sp
import math

from dataclasses import dataclass
 
x,y,z,t = sp.symbols('x,y,z,t', real=True)
 
c = 299792
 
@dataclass
class Vertexer:
 
    roc: list
 
    def err(self, x, y, z, data):
        arrival_at_i = math.sqrt((x - self.roc[0][0])**2 + (y - self.roc[0][1])**2 + (z - self.roc[0][2])**2) / c
        arrival_at_j = math.sqrt((x - self.roc[1][0])**2 + (y - self.roc[1][1])**2 + (z - self.roc[1][2])**2) / c
        arrival_at_k = math.sqrt((x - self.roc[0][0])**2 + (y - self.roc[0][1])**2 + (z - self.roc[0][2])**2) / c
 
        return (arrival_at_i - data[0])**2 + (arrival_at_j - data[1])**2 + (arrival_at_k - data[2])**2
 
    def find(self, data, xm, ym, zm):
        eq1=sp.Eq((self.roc[0][0] - x)**2 + (self.roc[0][1] - y)**2 + (self.roc[0][2] - z)**2 - c**2 * (data[0] - t)**2, (self.roc[1][0] - x)**2 + (self.roc[1][1] - y)**2 + (self.roc[1][2] - z)**2 - c**2 * (data[1] - t)**2)
        eq2=sp.Eq((self.roc[0][0] - x)**2 + (self.roc[0][1] - y)**2 + (self.roc[0][2] - z)**2 - c**2 * (data[0] - t)**2, (self.roc[2][0] - x)**2 + (self.roc[2][1] - y)**2 + (self.roc[2][2] - z)**2 - c**2 * (data[2] - t)**2)
        eq3=sp.Eq((self.roc[1][0] - x)**2 + (self.roc[1][1] - y)**2 + (self.roc[1][2] - z)**2 - c**2 * (data[1] - t)**2, (self.roc[2][0] - x)**2 + (self.roc[2][1] - y)**2 + (self.roc[2][2] - z)**2 - c**2 * (data[2] - t)**2)
 
        soln = sp.solve((eq1,eq2,eq3))
 
        fx = 0; fy = 0; fz = 0; px = 0; err1 = 100; err2 = 0
 
        for i in range(-100, 100):
            for j in range(-100, 100):
                px = self.err(soln[x].subs([(y, i), (z, j)])
                err2 = self.err(soln[x].subs([(y, i), (z, j)]), i, j, data)
                if(err2 < err1):
                    err1 = err2
                    fx = px; fy = i; fz = j
 
        print('soln', fx,fy,fz, error)
```

*Outside of the loop in question, there are, of course, a few obvious improvements that can be made here... this is far from finished, and there are some things I haven't yet gotten around to. As of now, the loop referenced is the clear performance "bottleneck".*

Comment: The comments you received that this question is somehow unsuitable for Stack Overflow were, regrettably *wrong*. I have deleted those incorrect comments.  You are asking a specific question about how to optimize code. This does not need to be migrated anywhere. It would not even necessarily be *appropriate* on another site. However, if you really want to move it elsewhere, then you don't need a moderator's help. Just delete it here and ask it fresh on another site.

Comment: The usual solution is to do task in parallel, have you tried splitting the range in the inner loop (for a start) then run those splits in parallel?

Comment: It sounds like if you include the least squares criterion as an equation then the system is not underdetermined any more. Can `solve` just give you the answer directly?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I'm not sure I follow. Could you elaborate? So far, I've been unable to write  a system that is directly solvable by `solve()`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to minimise err which is something that depends on y and z. Can you not just solve `err.diff(y)` and `err.diff(z)` for `y` and `z`? I can't tell what kind of equations that would give because the code as shown is not runnable.